# Need to set SameSite Cookie in a shopify APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cookies, shopify, samesite

I have a Shopify store and have created an APP using Ruby on Rails (Ruby version 2.4.0). The App is deployed on Heroku.

As Google updates the cookie by adding the "SameSite" attribute to make it more secure. I am not sure how to set the SameSite attribute in my APP.

In the APP no cookie is used, still when I follow the below steps:

1. Download Chrome Canary, then install and launch it.
2. In Canary, navigate to chrome://settings/help and verify that you see Google Chrome is up to date, if not then update Canary.
3. Navigate to chrome://flags/#samesite and enable these three SameSite flags:

   > SameSite by default cookies.
   >   Enable removing SameSite=None cookies.
   >   Cookies without SameSite must be secure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.